# Wordpress custom contact form, not sure where to start

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, templates

Alright, so. I've tried many different methods, as well as looked at several videos on this subject. But, i'm not making any progress. I have no idea where I am supposed to begin w/ this.

I created my own template for my portfolio. W/ its own custom form. And I want to recieve the messages put into this form and send them to my email.

So far, none of the methods I have tried on my own have worked. Below, is the form itself. Any help is appreciated.

```
<!-- searchform.php -->

<form class="contact-form" action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" method="post">

    <!-- form row 1 -->
    <input class="form" type="text" placeholder="Name" value="<?php echo get_search_query(); ?>" name="name" required>

    <!-- form row 2 -->
    <input class="form" type="email" placeholder="Email" value="<?php echo get_search_query(); ?>" name="email" required>

    <!-- form row 3 -->
    <input class="form" type="text" placeholder="Title" value="<?php echo get_search_query(); ?>" name="title" required>
    
    <!-- form row 4 -->
    <textarea class="form" placeholder="Your Message" name="message" required></textarea>

    <!-- form row 5 -->
    <input class="form-button" type="submit" name="submit">

</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does depend on which theme builder you're using (Elementor, Avada, Divi, etc.) because each of them come in-built with their own form which is highly customisable and will likely contain all the options you're looking for.

But I think it might be best to use a plugin for forms because I've found when trying to custom-code things Wordpress tends to have issues with that in unexpected places. The plugin I use when not the theme builder's, is **Contact Form 7**. It gives the fewest issues and allows you a fair amount of customisation. Whatever you can't style in the form itself can always be done in the custom CSS section.

Comment: Thank You! I was wondering about some issues I might have trying to custom code this form. I'm not using a theme builder (not yet anyway) for this template. But if you recommend it, i'll use the plugin, and learn how to custom code the form at another time.